# avoid getting 504 response from NGINX

Tags: nginx, timeout, reverse-proxy, gateway, connection-timeout

I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy for a new webapp interface over an *old* service.

NGINX serves the static resources and forwards the API requests over to the *old* server (also hiding it from the public, as it cannot have an A+ SSL setup)

Time to time I receive 504 gateway timeout responses, It feels like NGINX re-uses connections and the webserver from the other side doesn't respond anymore after re-using it for **too** long.

The solution is *very easy*, a simple `sudo service nginx restart` fixes those gateway timeouts, still I would like to fix this "glitch" once and for all.

Simple diagram:

```
Users              New Website (NGINX)              Old Website (ASP?)
  /           <<<   serves index.html
  /api/item   <<<   change headers and forward  >>>  API request  >\ 
                                                                   |
              <<<   change headers and forward <<<   API response </
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP status 504 means that the upstream server is down or slow to respond within your specified timeout.

Increase your `proxy_<*>_timeout` and reload nginx.

Find the directives here -
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html